# Will my code run if I copy from my windows to mac

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I’m currently making an app for android using Cordova and android studio. If I copy my codes from windows to Mac will it work on my Mac?

Answer (score 1):

It should, but **just to make sure** I would:

- Use latest versions of Android Studio on both systems
- Install the exact same version of Cordova CLI on both
- Download exactly the same Android SDK items
- Create the same AVD (if any) in both systems
- Make sure any other component that must be installed on both ends is the same version.